# matrix product boundary

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

If I have vector $I\in \mathbb{R}^{M \times 1}$ in which $I_{min} \leq I_{i} \leq I_{max}$ and matrix $W=Adiag(BI)$ can I say that $W$ is bounded as well?

$\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{P \times N}$, $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$ and both are positive matrix.

for example: 
$Adiag(BI_{min}) \leq W \leq Adiag(BI_{max})$

Comment: What is $Adiag$?

Comment: A is a matrix and diag: When x is a vector, a matrix with vector x on the diagonal will be returned.